# Config Gigablast search engine

Tags: search-engine

I have a CentOS 6 server.
Now to install Gigablast search engine on it.
I follow this guide case for ReadHat. http://www.gigablast.com/faq.html#src
After run make -j 4. I run './gb 0' to start your a single gigablast node.
Then I access to my server via IP address: x.x.x.x:8000, but I get message "This webpage is not available"
Could someone tell me why I get this error.
I can't see the error in my log file.
And this is my log content.

```
db: Logging to file /dev/stderr.
db: Use 'gb -d' to run as daemon. Example: gb -d
1447962510128 000 conf: Gigablast Version: Nov 19 2015 19:37:46
1447962510128 000 conf: Gigablast Architecture: 64-bit 
1447962510128 000 host: Working directory is /root/open-source-search-engine-master/
1447962510128 000 host: Using /root/open-source-search-engine-master/hosts.conf
1447962510128 000 host: Process ID is 9751
1447962510128 000 host: Detected local ip 127.0.0.1
1447962510128 000 host: Detected local ip x.x.x.x
1447962510128 000 host: Running as host id #0
1447962510374 000 wikt: Loading /root/open-source-search-engine-master/wiktionary-syns.dat
1447962510499 000 wikt: Loading /root/open-source-search-engine-master/wiktionary-buf.txt
1447962510552 000 wikt: test "love" -> "en|love,loved,loving,loves"
1447962510552 000 wiki: Loading /root/open-source-search-engine-master/wikititles2.dat
1447962510635 000 mem: addMem(100663296): tbl-wiki. ptr=0x7fcbfa33e014 used=127113172
1447962510727 000 db: Loading conf for collection main (0)
1447962510997 000 mem: addMem(349869920): buckets-posdb. ptr=0x7fcbe4b1d014 used=238787108
1447962511145 000 mem: addMem(193164080): mem-titledb. ptr=0x7fcbd8bce014 used=596421652
1447962511629 000 mem: addMem(100000022): mem-spiderdb. ptr=0x7fcbc4273014 used=1035055046
1447962511950 000 db: Verifying shard parity for posdb of 64000 bytes for coll main (collnum=0)...
1447962511950 000 db: Verifying shard parity for titledb of 640000 bytes for coll main (collnum=0)...
1447962511950 000 db: Verifying shard parity for tagdb of 64000 bytes for coll main (collnum=0)...
1447962511950 000 db: Verifying shard parity for clusterdb of 64000 bytes for coll main (collnum=0)...
1447962511950 000 db: Verifying shard parity for linkdb of 64000 bytes for coll main (collnum=0)...
1447962511950 000 db: Verifying shard parity for spiderdb of 64000 bytes for coll main (collnum=0)...
1447962511950 000 db: Verifying shard parity for doledb of 64000 bytes for coll main (collnum=0)...
1447962512158 000 mem: addMem(109051904): udictht. ptr=0x7fcbac23c014 used=1429646307
1447962512161 000 table: grewtable udictht from 2097152 to 8388608 slots in 78 ms (this=0x1be9ba0) (used=0)
1447962512530 000 gb: unifiedDict-buf.txt or unifiedDict-map.dat checksum is not approved for live service (1974148069587949864 != -14450509118443930)
1447962512530 000 speller: turning off spell checking for now
1447962512593 000 mem: addMem(109051904): tbl-lang. ptr=0x7fcba5a3b014 used=1511435235
1447962512594 000 lang: Successfully Loaded 0 Language Lists and 0 duplicate word hashes.
1447962512594 000 cat: Error opening structure file: /root/open-source-search-engine-master/catdb/gbdmoz.structure.dat
1447962512594 000 cat: Loading Categories From /root/open-source-search-engine-master/catdb/gbdmoz.structure.dat Failed.
1447962512594 000 cat: Loaded Categories From /root/open-source-search-engine-master/catdb/gbdmoz.structure.dat.
1447962512595 000 admin: Loading hashtable from /root/open-source-search-engine-master/catcountry.dat
1447962512614 000 autoban: read 0 entries
1447962512649 000 udp: Listening on UDP port 9000 with niceness=2 and fd=3.
1447962512649 000 db: Loading cache from /root/open-source-search-engine-master//dns.cache
1447962512653 000 udp: Listening on UDP port 5998 with niceness=1 and fd=4.
1447962512653 000 dns: Sending requests on client port 5998 using socket descriptor 4.
1447962512653 000 dns: Using nameserver 8.8.8.8:53.
1447962512653 000 dns: Using nameserver 8.8.4.4:53.
1447962512658 000 https: Reading SSL certificate from: /root/open-source-search-engine-master/gb.pem
1447962512659 000 http: Listening on TCP port 8000 with sd=5
1447962512659 000 https: Listening on TCP port 7000 with sd=6
1447962512670 000 build: Loading 8 bytes from /root/open-source-search-engine-master/addsinprogress.dat
1447962512686 000 db: gb is now ready
1447962512737 000 spider: made spidercoll=7925150 for cr=2501800
1447962512738 000 spider: hit spider queue rebuild timeout for main (0)
1447962512738 000 spider: rebuild complete for main. Added 0 recs to waiting tree, scanned 0 bytes of spiderdb.
1447962512778 000 gb: clock is now synced with host #0.
1447962519926 000 thread: Using 36708352 bytes for 20 thread stacks.
```

Answer (score 1):

gigablast starts on server on port 8000 by default, try changing your port to 8000

> http://x.x.x.x:8000